# In AWS Glue, how do I apply resolveChoice to a struct element within an array in a DynamicFrame?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

How do I apply resolveChoice to a struct element within an array inside a DynamicFrame?

**DynamicFrame Schema for reference**

```
|-- ColumnA: string
|-- ColumnB: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- ColumnC: string 
|    |    |-- ColumnD: choice
|    |    |    |-- double
|    |    |    |-- int
```

I want to apply resolveChoice to Column D. This would usually be resolved by below line if ColumnD was at root level.

`df = df.resolveChoice(specs = [('ColumnD', 'cast:double')])`

But how do I do the same within an array of struct?

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved with below code snippet

`df = df.resolveChoice(specs = [("ColumnB[].ColumnD", "cast:double")])`